# Execute windows program from SQL

Tags: windows, execute, skype

Do you know how can I execute a Windows application from SQL server? I have written a Windows application (actually it is a EXE file), when it runs by double clicks, it can call to Skype (I am working on Skype API). But when I try to execute it from inside SQL, it will never call to Skype.

I have used xp_cmdshell SP from SQL. I also tried to use this solution from CodeProject. But both of them did not work for me: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xyprocedure.aspx

Any help is appriciated!

Thanks and regards,
Leo

Comment: **why on earth** would you want to call Skype from within SQL Server!?!?!?!?!?!?

Answer (score 2):

When you execute an external application through xp_cmdshell it will be run by the SQL Server Service account, on the Services desktop. Skype is probably running under your account on the interactive desktop. It's no way you can succeed with that approach. Services are not meant to directly interact with a client program that way.

Instead you have to create small program that runs on *your* desktop under your credentials. That program would regularly check some kind of work queue in the database. Each work item should contain the information that the small program needs to be able to interact with Skype.